# How to configure xrandr or Gnome desktop environment to treat two or more physical monitors as 1 large display?

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, xorg, display, xinerama

I have two 1920x1080 monitors connected to a computer. I currently have a layout with the two displays configured horizontally like in figure A.

Instead I would like to have the system treat the two monitors as a single 3840x1080 display as in figure B.

```
Figure A
+---------------------+---------------------+
|                     |                     |
|  Display 1          |  Display 2          |
|  1920x1080+0+0      |  1920x1080+1920+0   |
|                     |                     |
|                     |                     |
|                     |                     |
+---------------------+---------------------+

Figure B
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                           |
|  Display 1                                |
|  3840x1080+0+0                            |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Here is what I tried so far:

- Setting up a virtual monitor using `xrandr --setmonitor` feature following the responses from this post: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=214841. Nothing seems to change.
- I tried to use xorg configuration generated by **Nvidia X Server Settings** and enabling the xinerama option. The screens were both black.

I messed with xrandr commands in an attempt to obtain the result I am looking for and eventually got something that partially worked.

Here's a shell script that sort of achieves what I am trying to do:

```sh
#/bin/sh

monitor1="DP-5"
monitor2="DP-1"
screenres="3840x1080"
offset="1920x0"

# Reset
xrandr --output $monitor1 --primary --pos 0x0 --panning 0x0 --size $screenres
xrandr --output $monitor2 --pos 0x0 --panning 0x0 --size $screenres

# Enable panning on both monitors
xrandr --fb $screenres
xrandr --output $monitor1 --panning $screenres --output $monitor2 --panning $screenres

xrandr --output $monitor2 --panning 0x0
xrandr --output $monitor2 --pos $offset

sleep 2
xrandr --output $monitor1 --panning 0x0
```

Extra details about the environment I am working with:
**Ubuntu:** 20.04 LTS
**Gnome:** v3.36.9
**GPU:** NVIDIA RTX A4000
**GPU Driver:** nvidia 470.141.03